Under what circumstances will `LOWER` in Postgres fail for non-English language?
I am trying to create a table with the following schema,
   CREATE TABLE "word_tokens" (
       "token_id" bigint generated always as identity,
       "word" varchar(400),
       primary key ("token_id"),
       check constraint "cc_word_tokens_lower" (LOWER("word") = "word")
   )
   CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "ux_word_tokens_words" ON "word_tokens" ("word");

The idea behind this is that insert should only accept lowercase words before inserting.
Now my backend is nodejs, and I am using the following,
   word = word.toLocaleLowerCase();
   pg.query `INSERT INTO "word_tokens"("word") VALUES (${word});`

My question is, is there any case when JavaScript's toLocaleLower will fail with LOWER in Postgres in any non-English language?

Should I use normalize?
Or should I use string.toLowerCase() instead of string.toLocaleLowerCase() in JavaScript?
Or should I use UPPER case? Which one should give least failure?

I have seen this answer, lower function in postgres , and when I run select lower('Ş') = 'ş' I get true.
Although this is working correctly for now, I want to know when this can fail.

There are writing systems which do not support case distinctions but Latin accented characters are not an example of those. Try Hebrew, Korean, Thai, Hindi, or Chinese; but my expectation would be that case conversion is simply a no-op in those scripts.

@tripleee I have tried Hindi and so far the trick is working.

If the implementations have different locales, one well-known problem character is I, which in English downcases to i but in Turkish to ı (dotless i).

@TobySpeight can you provide word with Tuurkish I that will fail for LOWER and will work for toLocaleLower in JavaScript?

How letters are converted to lower case depends on the locale implementation, in particular on the LC_CTYPE aspect of the locale.
PostgreSQL uses locales defined by either the C library or the ICU library or (from v17 on) its built-in locale provider. If Javascript uses a different implementation, you should not assume that lower-casing in Javascript works the same as lower-casing in PostgreSQL.

If your Javascript uses the ICU library, make sure that you create your PostgreSQL database with an ICU locale, which is not the default, and that you use the same locale as you are using in Javascript:
CREATE DATABASE db
   TEMPLATE template0
   LOCALE_PROVIDER icu
   ICU_LOCALE "de-AT"
   LOCALE "de_AT.utf8";

You still need to specify a C library locale for other locale aspects.

NodeJS and Chrome JavaScript also uses ICU (as v8 is linked to icu). If I use only string.toLowerCase() in JavaScript, would it match always?
